# Does the PIE.htc hack work in email?

Tags: html, css, email, css3pie

I'm on a mission to create a rock-solid email framework that pushes modern web development and design patterns for clients such as Apple Mail and Sparrow but that graceful degrades for Yahoo!, Gmail, Hotmail, etc.

Will including the [PIE.htc hack](http://css3pie.com/) work for older email clients?

Comment: Probably not. Web based clients are going vary depending on the browser used and most will likely strip the htc file out anyway.  Desktop clients such as outlook are all over the map.  With old versions using IE as rendering engine and new versions like outlook 2010 using MS Word as a rendering engine.  HTC is specific to IE.  Other clients wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Figured. Although, at least Outlook 2011 **for Mac** is using Webkit as a rendering engine instead of MS Word. What if I imported a stylesheet  via `<style type="text/css">@import url(css/main.css);</style>` that uses `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` on the desired element?

Comment: Again I am going to say no.  It is my understanding that htc is an IE only thing and it also requires javascript to run.  javascript is disabled in emails for security reasons.  From my experience the best way to make cross platform html emails is to stick with tables for layout, keep the css inline and use images for fancy things like rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not work because the .htc file needs to be served up by the web server hosting the page. Although the Email contains HTML, is not a web page.

Comment: It's not a web page but it can be viewed in a browser?

Comment: No, it will not work because the mail host, such as Gmail, will not be serving your PIE.HTC file.